# htaccess - Rewrite Path to Arguments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up custom rewriting scheme for my website (http://panchr.me).

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} repositories
RewriteRule ^(.+)repositories(.+) $1repositories?repo=$2 [nocase,last]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [nocase,last]
```

Specifically, I want to rewrite something such as `http://panchr.me/repositories/some_name` to `http://panchr.me/repositories?repo=some_name`. However, if I visit this page, I get a 404 Error. In addition, just visiting `http://panchr.me/repositories` now gives me a 500 Error.

How can I fix this?

My server structure is as follows:

```
.htaccess
# a few other files, not available to user
public_html/ # this is the DocumentRoot
    index.php
    repositories.php
    # more files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions and rule make no sense, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(repositories)(\.php)?/([^/]+)$ $1.php?repo=$3 [NC,L]
# alternatively to the above RerwriteRule you could try 
# (comment the above RewriteRule if u do and leave the conditions uncommented)
#RewriteRule ^(repositories)(?:\.php|)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?repo=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It pretty much says, if file or folder does not exist with the 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then the `RewriteRule` says, redirect anything that is `repositories/anything`, for example:

```
http://panchr.me/repositories/moduleA
http://panchr.me/repositories/other
http://panchr.me/repositories/some_name
```

Comment: Is it also possible to (optionally) match `repositories.php/some_name`? I tried the RewriteRule as `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)(repositories)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)$ $1$2.php?repo=$3 [NC,L]`, but this does not provide it as an argument. (I had to use the `([^\.]+)` initially because I could not set the RewriteBase without messing up another rule).

Comment: @RushyPanchal So where exactly is `repositories`? perhaps if you tell me more about your structure I could give you a better answer. `([^\.]+)` matches anything not a dot, what are you expecting to match that would come before `repositories`? **Is the other rule that messes up with the `RewriteBase` the bottom rule to redirect folders to their respective `php` if exist?**

Comment: I updated my original question with the server structure. Essentially, `.htaccess` is located in the _parent directory_ of `repositories.php`. My addition to your answer was the `(?:\.php)?`, which should be an optional match of `.php`. I want the rewrite to be able to do this:

`panchr.me/repositories/test` -> `panchr.me/repositories.php?repo=test` (this works already)
`panchr.me/repositories.php/test` -> `panchr.me/repositories.php?repo=test` (this does not work).